# How to write path redirect in ruby on rails and angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

Sorry that I am new to ruby on rails.

I am trying to create a directive in angularjs. 
What I was doing is create an html file in folder view/forms, named topRight-buttonGroup.html

Then I just created a simple directive for test:

```
app.directive('topRightButtonTools', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        templateUrl: 'topRight-buttonGroup.html'
    };
});
```

But getting the error message in the console is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Am I missing something should be done on ruby on rails? Or should I write some redirect code and save in somewhere?

my full folder structure is:

[image: Here is my structure]

Comment: Where you putting your html file?

Comment: @BKM I put html file in folder view/forms, as the post say

Comment: What you get if you give full path to your template in your directive?

Comment: @BKM still the same error

Comment: Try templateUrl: 'views/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html'

Comment: @BKM tried, it will go to http://localhost:3000/forms/views/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html and 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Could you provide your full folder structure?

Comment: Is your views folder inside app folder?

Comment: @BKM yes, my views folder inside the app folder

Comment: then try app/views/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html

Comment: @BKM no, it will go to  http://localhost:3000/*forms*/app/views/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: localhost:3000*forms* where this forms coming from?

Comment: Are you putting all your project files inside this forms folder and hosting in your server?

Comment: @BKM actually, if you go the path app/views/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html , it will redirect to localhost:3000/forms/app/views/forms/topRight-buttonGroup.html, it's the rails setting i think

Comment: @BKM are you still there?

Comment: It should work on my comment as I am doing it in my projects too. If its the rail issue you think, you need to check for it

Comment: @BKM can I email you the folder, and help me to check?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the form to be accessible so, create a folder inside **public**/ as **forms**/ and have the file placed there. Only content inside the public dir are rendered directly.

Unlike core php or other such scripting languages, RoR requires controllers to render actions which arent merely files that are interpreted. Also, routes are to be defined in config/routes.rb.

Refer:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/statische_webseiten.html